# Disable YouTube Auto Play in Watch Later

Tags: youtube, youtube-watch-later

I'm looking for a way to disable YouTube's autoplay feature when watching videos from the Watch Later playlist. Previously it was possible to disable autoplay in Watch Later, and the setting was persistent for other videos on Watch Later too.

To clarify: with autoplay, I don't mean that videos shouldn't automatically start playing, I would like that. Autoplay is the feature that *automatically advances to the next video in the playlist after one video has finished playing*.

YouTube used to remember the setting, but it has been changed. Right now playing a video from Watch Later always turns autoplay back on.

Comment: Yes, quite annoying. Especially when I am trying to read the comments below the video. Suddenly it goes to the next video, which marks it as watched too.

Comment: YouTube now do remember this setting

Answer (score 1):

The **Auto Play** toggle is saved between different visits, maybe it wasn't that way at the time you asked the question, but now it does.

I switched to another video, tried closing the tab/browser - the setting is still kept.

[image]

---

[Iridium](https://github.com/ParticleCore/Iridium) among other things, disables the auto-play of YouTube - which also apply to the watch later playlist.

The player will switch to the next video in the watch later list, but won't auto-play it.

Comment: we are talking about for WATCH LATER not "up next"

Answer (score -2):

try the no flash extension in firefox or chrome web browser, it allows you to click when to play the flash. Also youtube on the left hand side has a autoplay 'button' click on that to . However the noflash is for all sites including facebook etc twitter.